# Issue in SXA search scope: no results due to searchable_b:(True)

Tags: content-search, solr, sxa

I am using SXA in Sitecore 9, I have created simple search scope with below query:

```
template:{cbb0f1aa-1a19-4c0a-a897-49af144cb801};+location:{3F38A230-25BB-4DBA-B9D3-2CE94F842072}
```

From UI there are search result returned, however when I add Search result rendering in a page and use the search scope above, no results return in the page.
I checked Search log and I found the query issued from UI is:

```
12548 12:41:09 INFO  Solr Query - ?q=(((_path:(3f38a23025bb4dbab9d32ce94f842072) AND _template:(cbb0f1aa1a194c0aa89749af144cb801)) AND _latestversion:(1)) AND _datasource:(sitecore))&start=0&rows=20&fl=*,score&fq=_indexname:(sitecore_master_index)&wt=xml
```

From Search Result Rendering:

```
26128 12:29:08 INFO  Solr Query - ?q=(((_path:(3f38a23025bb4dbab9d32ce94f842072) AND _template:(cbb0f1aa1a194c0aa89749af144cb801)) AND (_path:(3f38a23025bb4dbab9d32ce94f842072) AND searchable_b:(True))) AND _latestversion:(True))&rows=0&fq=_indexname:(sitecore_master_index)&wt=xml
```

the difference is **searchable_b:(True)**, how we can set this field and what does it mean?

Comment: I assume you have a checkbox field named 'searchable '. You need to check this for the items you want to show in your results, and then publish

Comment: i am using the OOB Page template provided by SXA, that found under  /sitecore/templates/Project/[Talent Name]/Page

Comment: I'm not sure about the template you're referring to, but it (or templates it inherits) should have a field named 'Searchable', do you see it in the template's standard value or not?

Comment: Yes , its inherit from : (1) Page - /sitecore/Templates/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Multisite/Content/Page
(2) Standard template - /sitecore/Templates/System/Templates/Standard template

Comment: Does the Content/Page template contain a 'Searchable' field?

Comment: its inhered form "_ISearchable" but there is no check box to mark in content editor , the ssearch result work from with when i apply it with sitecore 8 and Lucene search

Comment: _Searchable turned out to be a computed field. It returns True if the item inherits 'Searchable'. However I also just noticed in your final query, the number of rows to get is 0. So you're telling the index to get 0 results.

Answer (score 2):

'searchable_b:(True)' is a computed field (part of SXA) that returns true if the item inherits 'Searchable' template. So if your page templates inherit 'Searchable' (directly or indirectly) you should be good, but make sure to publish.

Your main problem seems that the query is requesting 0 rows. Maybe the 'Page Size' in your search component has been set to 0 by mistake.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The field `"searchable_b":true`

you need to include the base template and a few more settings, As mentioned below.

[image]

By default all pages under home is "searchable_b":true but for all data items, you need to add configure a few more settings -

Go to settings --> Associated Content and select those data

After that perform the reindex, this will update the index to "searchable_b":true

Example below -

1. Data items with _Searchable temmplate but without setting configuration

[image]

2. Data items with _Searchable template and with setting configuration

[image]

For more troubleshooint steps, you can check here - 
http://jitendrasoni.blogspot.com/2020/04/sxa-search-result-tips-for.html

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing issue due to searchable_b field. When I was trying to query in solr dashboard UI and querying with searchable_b field, I was not able to get results. Actually the reason was searchable_b field not getting indexed. So I added this field under  node in solr config and rebuilded index again. It worked for me.

```
<field fieldName="searchable">Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.ComputedFields.Searchable, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search</field>
```